# how to get fragment Identifier out in azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, spring-cloud

Here is my code in java

```
@FunctionName("myTest")
public HttpResponseMessage execute(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        ExecutionContext context) {

    String uri = request.getUri().toString();
```

This is the only method in HttpRequestMessage to get uri. I sent request `http://localhost:7071/api/myTest?abc=1111#fragmentIdentifier=123`

Here is what it shows. It doesn't read the full uri with fragmentIdentifier

[image]

Did I do anything wrong? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

> Did I do anything wrong? Any suggestion?

In HTTP requests, the fragment identifier is not sent to the server. Therefore, when you access the URI using `request.getUri().toString()` in your Java code, you won't get the fragment identifier because it's not part of the request URI that's sent to the server.

```java
package com.function;

import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

public class HttpTriggerJava1 {

    @FunctionName("HttpTriggerJava1")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        // Parse query parameter
        String uri = request.getUri().toString();
        String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
        String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);

        if (name == null) {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name value on the query string or in the request body").build();
        } else {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + name+ "\nURL= "+uri).build();
        }
    }
}
```

## `OUTPUT`:

[image]

[image]